# How to pass the ng-model value to ng-repeat orderby

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am taking as input the sort parameter (date, author), How to use this values that I have aquired using ng-model to pass to order-by in ng-repeat so as to sort according to what is entered in the input field. I want to use {{dishCtrl.dish.sort}} as an input value in place of date in order-by. However if i Straight away right that down as a predicate to order-by it does not work.

```
<h3 style="display: inline-block; margin-right:10px">Customer Comments</h3> 

<p style="display: inline-block">Sort by: <input type="text" ng-model="dishCtrl.dish.sort"></p>

<blockquote ng-repeat="comment in dishCtrl.dish.comments | orderBy: 'date' ">
    <p>{{comment.rating}} Stars</p>
    <p>{{comment.comment}}</p>
    <footer>{{comment.author}}, {{comment.date | date:'MMM, d, y'}}    </footer>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: Have you tried <blockquote ng-repeat="comment in dishCtrl.dish.comments | orderBy: dishCtrl.dish.sort">?

Comment: Yes, It does not work

Comment: It works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/CcLLl11l6M49iKur8YbK?p=preview

Comment: Did you solve this? Otherwise, can you replicate your problem in a Plunker?